# How to download images with the help of list urls and python,but not all the urls are active?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to download tennis ball images from the image-net data set with the help of urls given in their website, but my code always stop executing after it reaches a url that doesn't exist.

```
import requests
path = "./imageslist.txt"
j = 0
file1 = open(path,'r')
for i in file1.readlines():
         imagename = "Image{0}.jpg".format(j)
         result = requests.get(i)
         if result.status_code == 200:
            print(i)
            image = result.raw.read()
            open(imagename,"wb").write(image)
         j = j+1
```

It shows this error :

```
ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.jpmorganchaseopen.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /images/tennisball.jpg%0A (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000186FDAD0A08>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo 
failed'))
```

How do I handle this error?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import requests
path = "./imageslist.txt"
with open(path, 'r') as file1:
    all_links = [i.strip() for i in file1.readlines()]
    j = 0
    imagename = f"Image{j}.jpg"
    for link in all_links:
        result = requests.get(link)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            try:
                image = result.raw.read()
                open(imagename, "wb").write(image)
            except Exception:
                pass
        else:
            pass
        j += 1
```

You need to strip the link of any delimiters like `'\n'` present while doing `file1.readlines()`. Also use f-strings (faster) in stead of `.format` formatting.

Comment: I am still getting the same error when it reaches a dead or a broken url,i want it to jump to the next one if it gets the same error

Comment: @HarshvardhanChandirasekar Could you please add the `imageslist.txt` file or specifically the links for which you're getting the error !